# config wizard fails at step 2 after creating database

Tags: wss-3.0, sql-server, configuration-wizard

I have been having a lot of trouble installing WSS 3.0 on windows server 2008, usign SQL 2008.

I have found often the solution where it asks to create the db usign the psconfig command line but without luck.

In the registry, the server role was WFE and when I changed it to APPLICATION, it is worst. The setup freezes.

I first made a mistake, installing wss as a standalone.... do you know any other reg key that might makes the connection to sql fails ?

It is weird since the setup creates 2 bd (config and admin content) and then cannot connects to it. WTF, you are able to creates those DB but can't connect to them ?

I have the same error when trying to connect to an existing farm. It's saying that sharepoint serivces are not initialized.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint requires a number of different accounts to install and run. The following link may be helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc263408(office.12).aspx

With respect to your fiirst problem, you probably can't connect to the database because the account that is being used by the WFE hasn't any rights to the DB. The account you installed with is probably not the account being used to access SQL Server. Without looking it up I'm pretty sure this account is the account your Application Pool runs under. Don't be tempted though to make this an administrator account as this isn't a member of IIS_WPG so can't run websites. Nor is this a sound security practice.

Secondly, once you run the installation process, you need to run the SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard. It's in the Start menu under Microsoft Office Server.

I'd also recommend leaving the registry alone.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks, I think the link you provided will help me a lot, since I always found articles about WS2003. I am usign my administrator account (a custom made administrator account) to install sharepoint and I created a seperate simple user for sharepoint to run with and connect to the DB. This user has the 3 security roles the sp config wizard has give him. Are you saying that this user must also be part of the IIS_WPG group ? The installation process went fine, it is the config wizard that fails after creating the 2 DB. I really apreciate your help ! Thanks

Comment: If your separate simple user is the account that the IIS App Pool runs under, then yes, it needs to be part of the IIS_WPG group. Membership of this group allows an account to run an IIS Web App (as distinguishable from a SPT Web App). So the account that runs your App Pool needs access to the DB. From memory, it also needs to be able to write to your 12 hive (you'd need to check). It should already be able to write somewhere so it can write IIS logs - I think this is your inetpub folder.